# Gradle creates circular dependency for runtime dependency

Tags: gradle, compilation, dependencies, runtime, circular-dependency

I have a mutli module gradle project:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
}

project(':core') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':module:mod-a')
    }
}

project(':module:mod-a') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}

project(':module:mod-b') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}
```

Of course this causes a circular compile dependency:

```
* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:core:compileJava
+--- :core:compileJava (*)
\--- :module:mod-a:compileJava
    +--- :core:compileJava (*)
    \--- :module:mod-a:compileJava (*)
```

What bothers me is that even if I change the `compile` dependency from `:core` to `:module:mod-a` to a `runtime` dependency it still is not possible to compile the project:

```
* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:module:mod-a:compileJava
\--- :module:mod-a:compileJava (*)
```

I don't see why there is a problem. The `:core` does need the module only at runtime and therefore can be compiled first. Afterwards the modules can be compiled using the core. Furthermore the `:core` is not part of the error message from Gradle anymore. So Gradle seems to "see" that it is just a runtime dependency.

Where is the problem and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `runtimeOnly` instead of `runtime` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with gradle, but adding runtimeOnly also not helping out

Comment: Figured out the issue. I am actually using spring-boot-plugin, this by default disables the normal jar creation task and builds bootJar by default. bootJar need to have all of runtime and compiletime dependencies and hence it was trying to build runtime dependencies also and so circular dependency issue occured. I disabled default bootJar by adding 'jar{enabled = true}' in the build.gradle file and the build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
dependencies {
    runtime project(':xxx')
}
```

It's the same as

```
dependencies {
    runtime project(path: ':xxx', configuration: 'default')
}
```

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations) which states that the `default` configuration extends `runtime`.

So by doing this you are making `:module:mod-a` depend on the `runtime` configuration from `:core`. Hence the curcular dependency

You could probably reference the `archives` configuration instead of `default` to break the cycle

eg:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
project(':core') {
    artifacts {
        archives jar
    }
}
project(':module:mod-a') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(path: ':core', configuration: 'archives')
        compile project(path: ':core', configuration: 'runtime')
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that `runtimeOnly` seems to run fine. But in your link it doesn't even seem to exist. What is `runtimeOnly`?